# Mob spawning platform isn't dark even without torches

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have started to build a mob far in Minecraft Pocket Edition. It is a basic farm built at exactly the height limit. You can see the outside in the picture below.

[image: The top of the mob farm]

The problem is inside the spawn platform, the light level stays the same as outside. For example, it looks as if sunlight is shining inside, but it is not.

[image]

The roof is made entirely out of full spruce wood plank block, and not slabs or stairs. Is this a glitch, or is it supposed to be like that? The ceiling is at exactly the height limit, which is 128 blocks in the current version. I am in Minecraft Pocket Edition version 0.13.1, the latest as of the start of 2016.

Is it because of the small distance from the height limit, or the tube? There is a Jack-o-lantern at the bottom of it, but a 55 block way down. The farm is directly above the world spawn, so there is a lowered part in the ceiling. I'm not sure if light can pass through the blocks at a diagonal edge, aslthough there are some cases where this can happen.

Comment: Not so sure about PE, but on the PC version, there's a bug where this happens in artificially closed-in spaces.

Comment: [This](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/173506/104387) question is pretty similar.

Answer (score 1):

This does seem to be a bug: blocks at the top of the world don't block sunlight. I would suggest reporting the issue at the [MCPE issue tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE); in the meantime as a workaround you can drop the ceiling down a block and that should fix it.